# How to select a user who has read Steven King and has not read William Shakespeare

Tags: mysql

While making my study mysql project, I failed to apply JOIN's knowledge in an empirical situation, have issues with the logic of the query itself.

My aim is to make a query that requires 6 tables to interact.

First connected table batch:

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `condition` ENUM('mint', 'new', 'medium', 'poor', 'needs replacement'),
  `date_added` DATE 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `authors` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `pseudonim` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `year_of_birth` INT(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

connected many-to-many via pivoting table

```
CREATE TABLE `authors_books` (
  `author_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `book_id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`author_id`, `book_id`),

CONSTRAINT `fk1_authors_authors_id` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `authors` (`id`) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE, 

CONSTRAINT `fk2_books_book_id` FOREIGN KEY (`book_id`) REFERENCES `books` (`id`) 
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The second batch is as it's seen on the screenshot - books, users and user_orders:
https://paste.pics/30d57ef8c6f5adfab23ce1158fb30f09

What I am trying is to get all users who have read King and haven't read Shakespeare.

I'm looking at it in the following way:

- addressing users table since I need a user: `SELECT * FROM  users`
- i need to search via books, so

  ```
  LEFT JOIN user_orders ON users.id = user_orders.user_id
  LEFT JOIN books ON user_orders.book_id = books.id
  ```

Following this logic, I ended up chaining dysfunctional JOINS, what am I missing? How should this logic be built?

Comment: Not the case. All info is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join 5 tables, group by user and set the conditions in the HAVING clause:

```
select
  u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name
from users u
inner join user_orders o on o.user_id = u.id
inner join books b on b.id = o.book_id
inner join authors_books ab on ab.book_id = b.id
inner join authors a on a.id = ab.author_id
group by u.id, u.first_name, u.last_name
having sum(a.name = 'Stephen King') > 0 and sum(a.name = 'William Shakespeare') = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need `Left Joins`, but you probably need a `NOT EXISTS` the following query should do it:

```sql
  SELECT u.* FROM users u
  INNER JOIN user_orders uo ON u.id=uo.user_id
  INNER JOIN books b ON uo.book_id=b.id
  INNER JOIN authors_books ab ON ab.book_id = b.id
  INNER JOIN authors a ON ab.author_id=a.id
  WHERE a.name = 'Steven King' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM users u2
      INNER JOIN user_orders uo2 ON u2.id=uo2.user_id AND uo2.user_id = uo.user_id
      INNER JOIN books b2 ON uo2.book_id=b2.id
      INNER JOIN authors_books ab2 ON ab2.book_id = b2.id
      INNER JOIN authors a2 ON ab2.author_id=a2.id
      WHERE a2.name = 'Shakespear')
```

Without sample data I can't test this.  It may be able to be simplified as it looks a bit ugly at the moment, but it should give you a starting point.

Comment: Yep. A bit ugly!

Comment: @AntG Thank you man, there is indeed a lot of things I will have to cope with to achieve this understanding, your example sheds enough light for me to continue.